# Sending a large text via Boost ASIO

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to send a **very large** string to one of my clients. I am mostly following code in HTTP server example: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html

Write callbacks return with error code 14, that probably means EFAULT, "bad address" according to this link:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/operating-system-error-codes/

Note that I could not use message() member function of error_code to read error message, that was causing segmentation fault. (I am using Boost 1.53, and the error might be due to this: https://github.com/boostorg/system/issues/50)

When I try to send small strings, let's say of size 10 for example, write callback does not return with an error.

Here is how I am using async_write:

```
void Connection::do_write(const std::string& write_buffer)
{
  auto self(shared_from_this());
  boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(write_buffer, write_buffer.size()),
      [this, self, write_buffer](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t transfer_size)
      {
        if (!ec)
        {

        } else {
          // code enters here **when** I am sending a large text.
          // transfer_size always prints 65535
        }
      });
}
```

Here is how I am using async_read_some:

```
void Connection::do_read()
{
  auto self(shared_from_this());
  socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer_),
      [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
      {
        if (!ec)
        {
           do_write(VERY_LARGE_STRING);
           do_read();
        } else if (ec != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) {
          connection_manager_.stop(shared_from_this());
        }
      });
}
```

What could be causing write callback to return with error with large string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The segfault indicates likely [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) to me.

Of course there's to little code to tell, but one strong smell is from you using a reference to a non-member as the buffer:

```
boost::asio::buffer(write_buffer, write_buffer.size())
```

Besides that could simply be spelled `boost::asio::buffer(writer_buffer)`, there's not much hope that `write_buffer` stays around for the duration of the asynchronous operation that depends on it.

As the documentation [states](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html#:%7E:text=Although%20the%20buffers%20object%20may%20be%20copied%20as%20necessary%2C%20ownership%20of%20the%20underlying%20memory%20blocks%20is%20retained%20by%20the%20caller%2C%20which%20must%20guarantee%20that%20they%20remain%20valid%20until%20the%20handler%20is%20called):

> Although the buffers object may be copied as necessary, ownership of the underlying memory blocks is retained by ***the caller***, which ***must guarantee that they remain valid until the handler is called***.

I would check that you're doing that correctly.

Another potential cause for UB is [when you cause overlapping writes](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html#:%7E:text=This%20operation%20is%20implemented%20in%20terms%20of%20zero%20or%20more%20calls%20to%20the%20stream%27s%20async_write_some%20function%2C%20and%20is%20known%20as%20a%20composed%20operation.%20The%20program%20must%20ensure%20that%20the%20stream%20performs%20no%20other%20write%20operations) on the same socket/stream object:

> This operation is implemented in terms of zero or more calls to the stream's async_write_some function, and is known as a composed operation. ***The program must ensure that the stream performs no other write operations*** (such as async_write, the stream's async_write_some function, or any other composed operations that perform writes) ***until this operation completes***.

If you checked both these causes of concern and find that something must be wrong, please post a new question including a fully selfcontained example ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) or [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Comment: It seems that I had a lifetime issue. I modified Connection class so that it would have a member as "std::string outgoing_buffer_" and then I assigned write_buffer to outgoing_buffer_. Since outgoing_buffer_ will live as long as the connection object it is contained within, I no longer have life time issues, and it seems to be working. About this "overlapping" issue, what exactly is it? If I have just a single thread from which I am calling io_context::run, should I still be worried about this?

Comment: Only if you post a new write operation before the previous one completed (hence: overlapping). The quoted documentation is ultra-precise in the wording, if you want it to be even more concrete.

Comment: as far as I understand, I could have also created a smart shared pointer to the write_buffer as well. That would also extend its life time till the handler completes. Other possible solution is using a global buffer that is guaranteed to live throughout the application. Do you agree with these options?

Comment: Not in general. Making that a member should suffice, since quite obviously the lifetime of `self` is already governed by a smart pointer. Global variables are always a bad idea.

Comment: I know it is a code smell, but that is an option. Would smart pointer option perform better? I would expect it to

Comment: It is still silly to put a smart pointer in an `enable_shared_from_this` object - unless you need to share ownership (and usually the lifetime is separate from the instance). Automatic storage duration is just so much simpler and performant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243537/discussion-between-aydin-ozcan-and-sehe).